# Is there a limitation on the number of recipients to send an SMS using Intent with ACTION_SENDTO?

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

I'm using the following code for sending sms messages using the sms app from my application:

```
String toNumbers = "";

for ( String s : numbersArrayList)  
{  
    toNumbers = toNumbers + s + ";"
}  

toNumbers = toNumbers.subString(0, toNumbers.length - 1);
String message= "this is a custom message";

Uri sendSmsTo = Uri.parse("smsto:" + toNumbers);
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, sendSmsTo);
                intent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
                startActivity(intent);
```

**The question:** is there a limitation for the number of numbers I can pass here in `numbersArrayList`? If this list is a 2000 items size, would it still work?

Comment: That will be up to the user's chosen SMS client.

Comment: @CommonsWare, then shouldn't it be up to the intent to provide me only with applications that can handle this specific number of recepients, as it handles the action type and provides me with applications that can handle this action?

Comment: "then shouldn't it be up to the intent to provide me only with applications that can handle this specific number of recepients" -- there is no means of expressing that in the `<intent-filter>` specifications, sorry.